# when material design library is added my date picker is not working

Tags: android, material-design

com.github.badoualy:datepicker-timeline:c6dcd05737
I am using this date picker library but when material design library is added my date picker library is not seeing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CZ8e.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try File > invalidate cache and restart. I have weird errors like that sometimes and this normally works. if not check your java files maybe something screwed up.

Comment: Try migrating to androidx.